# How can we get involved in Joomla! CMS Testing?

Tags: cms, cms-testing

I've been following the developer email threads and announcements as new Joomla! CMS versions make their way through Betas to Release Candidates to Production Releases.

Throughout the cycle, the Project Leadership Team (PLT) puts out the call to the community to assist with testing in order to resolve any bugs prior to Production Releases.

How can we in the community get involved in testing?

Are there specific prescribed test-case scenarios?

Is the PLT looking for folks with specific skill-sets?  If yes, which skill-sets?

It would be great if we can get a high-level overview and links to resources from somebody knowledgeable with Joomla! CMS Testing and how we can best be of assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, this is the best way I know to learn new skills and to understand how Joomla works. You are not giving back, but getting back a lot as well. Disclosure: I am a Joomla Bug Squad (JBS) member.

**Reading material**

Read more on the [JBS Portal Page](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aBug_Squad). To get a general idea, review all the articles from the portal page. It should give you a general overview.

**How can we in the community get involved in testing?**

The answer is simpler than you think: by testing, by using Joomla before it's GA (general availability). You can start reviewing the proposed betas or RCs for a specific version. Just install them on your own development / test installations and check if there are issues.

Report on the tracker for any issues you encounter. Check first if you are the first one reporting this or if this a older known issue is.

**Are there specific prescribed test-case scenarios?**

Generally you need to use your own business needs and test against them.

Testing is required on proposed fixes for known bugs or on new features. Each bug fix must have two people who tested it. This is actually an area where the the JBS is overwhelmed and needs as much help as it can get. Updates and new installations are also important. You will never run out of things to do.

**Is the JBS looking for folks with specific skill-sets? If yes, which skill-sets?**

Yes, all skill-sets :)

The Joomla! Bug Squad (JBS) is a team within the Production Working Groups. Their job is to identify and fix bugs in Joomla. See more at [Introduction to the Joomla! Bug Squad](http://docs.joomla.org/Bug_Squad)

The idea is that you can get involved no matter your skill-set.

**So how can I start, do I need to be a JBS member?**

No, you don't need to. You can start by checking the [Joomla Issue Tracker](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemBrowse&tracker_id=8103)

You can help by (setting the filter status) looking into issues that are:

- Open - issues that are not confirmed. Follow the replication instructions and see if you can replicate the issue.
- Pending - issues that are generally confirmed and have a fix. Try to replicate the issue and than apply the proposed patch. See if everything works good.

If after you've read an issue you feel that you understand it, look into it. If it's another language for you, just move on. There are all types of issues.

**Got more questions?**

If it fits the format for stackexchange ask it here, otherwise you can ask them in the [CMS Development Group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/joomla-dev-cms).

Answer (score 6):

I've also recently started testing.

- If PLT issues a *general call to test a whole Beta or RC version*, you can just download it, install and use it for development (not for a live site). If you find an issue, you can report it back to the Joomla general forum to confirm, search in the tracker if there's an already opened issue, or create a new issue.
- There's always a *constant need of testing new features or **bug fixes***. This is very specific. You have to access the tracker, read the instructions, apply a patch to a Joomla site, test the case, and report the result (*all issues require at least two successfull @test to be approved*)
- **Pizza, Bugs and Fun** It's a special chapter on Joomla! Events ;-) *And, a good way to start*. The event is global for virtual participants (both businesses and individuals), with local venues wherever they are organized. The key goal is to fix as many Joomla 3 and Joomla 2.5 bugs as possible. Example: http://docs.joomla.org/Pizza_Bugs_and_Fun_July_12,_2013

For more information:

- **If you want to test bug fixes (i.e. patches)**: http://docs.joomla.org/Pizza_Bugs_and_Fun_July_12,_2013#If_you_want_to_test_bug_fixes_.28i.e._patches.29
- Bug Tracking Process : http://docs.joomla.org/Bug_Tracking_Process

Comment: Great info.  Great links!

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing first: Anyone can help, it doesn't matter if you are a user or a developer or designer.

When testing betas or RCs, the best thing you can do is to use the CMS. Create articles, tag them, edit them, browse the site, ...
Do whatever you usually do when using Joomla. Look for anything which doesn't work as expected.

Usually the single changes are tested quite well. During beta and RC we want to find the unintended side effects. Those things which broke that nobody thought will break :)